# 2 Bit Adder Circuit not Functioning Correctly

Tags: circuit-analysis

I created this 2-bit adder circuit today, and every button combination works except when both A and B inputs are 1 (both buttons pressed down)

The button on the far left is the carry button (Sorry, I don't know the legitimate name for this input)

The ICs go in this order from left to right -> 74LS86, 74LS08, 74LS32

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question and add, 1st a schematic (use the respective button in the editor), and 2nd a truth table of what you expect and what you get instead.

Comment: I fail to see what could be two operand `2 Bit` with three inputs.

Comment: @greybeard I'm sure the OP means a "full adder" and simply counted the number of inputs without the carry-in. ;-) ItsAslan, please clarify in your question.

Comment: (If those aren't 5 V LEDs ("integrated" current limiting), your driving LS-TTL outputs, the LEDs, or, most likely, both out of spec even when "it works".)

Comment: [This is what you want to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSCYy.png) if you don't need a carry-in.

Comment: Have you applied an anti-bounce circuit to each button?

Comment: For full adder case, [this is what you need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHHlF.png).

Comment: @Franc As this is a pure combinatorial circuit watched by a human, there is no need to debounce.

Comment: without debounce it is excellent for lottery numbers!